# Integral of floor function times arbitrary function.

Tags: calculus, integration, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I was doing some work, and came across an integral in the form
$$\int_1^\infty [x] \phi'(x) dx$$
Assume $[x]\phi(x)$ vanishes at infinity.

Now, when I saw this, i was curious to try integration by parts.
So I got 
$$-\phi(1) - \int_1^\infty [x]' \phi(x) dx$$
From here, I tried to make the quick argument because $[x]'$ is undefined at countably many disconnect points, that I can remove those points from the domain of the integral, and conclude that integral is 0.
This seems to be wrong, however. Why is that?
Is there any way to solve an integral like this? 
Or is it simply that, the integral doesn't exist, in that choice of $f$ and $g$ in integration by parts.

Comment: The assumption of vanishing at Infinity, is it your assumption or part of problem statement? Because that definite integral may not exist for certain $\phi(x)$

Comment: Take it to be part of the problem statement, that is $\lim [x]\phi(x) =0$

Comment: For integration by parts, both functions must be continuously differentiable, shouldn't they?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably true, and would certainly explain why this isn't behaving rightly. Any thoughts on how to deal with an integral like this?

Comment: Break the limits, like 1 to 2, 2 to 3 and so on... Then floor function becomes a constant on that integral. Though the floor function is not differentiable at integer values, you can leave those points. This should work I think